# Postal code boundaries for India?

Tags: data-request, geospatial, postal-code, india, kml

I'm trying to find out where to download Postal Code boundaries (e.g. Shapefiles, GML, KML) for India. This data needs to be compatible with a typical GIS software (e.g. ArcGIS, QGIS).

Can someone point me to a data source for this?

Comment: Have you tried openstreetmap.org

Comment: Yes I have, but did not find boundaries. Can you try to find that?

Comment: As the answer to one of the cited gis.se questions (answer from Barry Carter) tells us `You won't find them, since no one (not even the Postal Department) has Authentic Boundaries.` I admire your persistence in trying to find them.  I suppose this begs the question, have you actually seen some resource that purports to have this information, and this is the source that you are looking for?

Comment: Would you be able to use generated(non-official) boundaries?

Answer (score 4):

Not an answer, but too long for a comment.

Possibly helpful links:

- https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/35669/indian-postcode-boundaries-required
- https://www.mbi-geodata.com/en/2013/04/11/press-release-new-postal-code-boundaries-for-india/ (not free, and linked page is in German)
- http://geoportal.gsdl.org.in/postal/ (and related pages)
- http://postalcode.globefeed.com/india_postal_code.asp (sublinks may be helpful, but are not in GIS format)
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/datameet/MWbzzQJ0BcI (one of a couple of pages that suggests this data isn't well-defined)

Possible duplicates:

- https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/121758/seeking-shapefile-for-postal-codes-zip-codes-of-india
- https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/77674/obtaining-postcode-boundaries-for-india

To be fair, this is all google stuff, so you've probably seen it.

Comment: I have seen all of this and nothing found... Maybe there is some solution to select specific postal code from some other data which contain  information about it (example from street data, buildings or something like that...).